# Force row referred to by foreign key to have the same different foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, articles and comments. The comments schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  in_response_to INTEGER REFERENCES comments(id),
  article_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES articles(id),
  // etc
);
```

I'd like to create a restriction that says that: new comments that are in response to an older comment must share the older comment's `article_id`.

How would I express this constraint in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use multi-column foreign key constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  in_response_to INTEGER ,
  article_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES articles(id),
  CONSTRAINT xx UNIQUE( id, article_id ),
  CONSTRAINT response_must_have_the_same_article_id
           FOREIGN KEY ( in_response_to, article_id )
           REFERENCES comments( id, article_id )
);
```

Comment: Thank you! For reference, the constraint `CONSTRAINT xx UNIQUE( id, article_id )` is required, or else Postgres will complain that `there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "comments"`